# error=13, Permission denied while executing script in Java

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a Java code which on execution will present a GUI button to user, and upon pressing it; a bash script would be executed. My script works on terminal,  but when I try to run the script in Java via Runtime.getRuntime().exec ,I am getting permission errors.I also used chmod 777 in my command but all in vain.

```
**MY Java code is** 
package com.interface_saad;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.File;
/**
 *
 * @author Saad
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static JFrame fr=new JFrame("QoS");
    static JPanel button_pan=new JPanel();
    static JButton QoSButton=new JButton("QoS");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final File file = null;

        button_pan.add(QoSButton);
        fr.add(button_pan,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setSize(200,200);

 QoSButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("path");
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /home/talal/enable.sh");
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./ /home/talal/enable.sh");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }


            }
        });


        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(fr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

**and my bash script is enable.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

(sleep 2
echo root
sleep 2
echo admin
sleep 1

echo '/usr/sbin/svqos status `get_wanface` 0'
sleep 2


echo '/usr/sbin/svqos `nvram get wshaper_downlink` `nvram get wshaper_uplink` `get_wanface` `nvram get wan_mtu` 0 '

sleep 1
echo '/usr/sbin/svqos status `get_wanface` 0'

sleep 4) | telnet 192.168.1.1 -l root
```

Need suggestions. I am in desperate need of help.

Comment: What on earth is `"./ /home/talal/enable.sh"`? If you want to execute a command, use its actual path; in this case, `"/home/talal/enable.sh"`.

Comment: `final File file = null;`  What was your reasoning to include that line?

Comment: @SaadSarwar If you (your program) cannot execute enable.sh, you can't change its mode, otherwise it'll be a security leak. Change its mode on terminal.

Comment: michaelb958 was right; By using the actual path, the script worked. Thanks